# Auto-populate date and username in sheet 2 based on data input in sheet 1

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I´m a relatively inexperienced when it comes the VBA, so I hope my problem is a quick-fix to all you masters out there:

**Background**
I have a filed that is used as an data input file, where different people insert data in different columns and in different rows. I have previously had a sort of "sign-off" section on the same sheet, where a cell is automatically populated with the users username and date. Hence when there are a large amount of users, it has been clear 1) by whom, and 2) at what point, data has been inserted to the file.

**What I need help with**
In order to reduce the amount of information on the same sheet I now want to have the "sign-off" section on another sheet. I.e. when *Steve* inserts data in, for example, cells F:15 and G:34 in Sheet 1, I want his username and the date to automatically be populated in the same cells (i.e. F:15 and G:34) in Sheet 2.

**Data input range**
In Sheet 1, from column 3 to column 36 & row 4 to row 44. For the sake of simplicity, I will make Sheet 2 to look exactly the same as Sheet 1. Hence same "output" range on Sheet 2.

**Current code**
This is my old code that I need help with re-writing so that the username and date is on Sheet 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range

If Target.Column >= 3 And Target.Column <= 36 And Target.Row >= 4 And Target.Row <= 44 Then
For Each c In Target
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.Offset(0, -6).Value = ClearContents
    Else
        c.Offset(0, -6).Value = Environ("username") & " " & Date
    End If
Next c
End If
```

Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to assign the value explicitly to Sheet 2. See below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range

If Target.Column >= 3 And Target.Column <= 36 And Target.Row >= 4 And Target.Row <= 44 Then

Dim ws2 as Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For Each c In Target

    If c.Value = "" Then 
        ws2.Range(c.Address).ClearContents
    Else
        ws2.Range(c.Address).Value = Environ("username") & " " & Date
    End If

Next c

End If
```